# How to make a slider vertically with lables?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create **`input="range"`** slider vertically.

I have created horizontally slider but when I create it vertically it's not showing **lables** with their name?

basically, I want to display this horizontal slider when on Laptop and vertically slider align in center when it's comes in phone ! I use media query for this but when it turn into vertically it's not showing labes?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.0.2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <style>
      datalist {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

      </style>
  <body>
      

<div class="container mt-4">
<br><br><br>

<input type="range" min="1" max="5" list="tickmarks" > 

<datalist id="tickmarks">
  <option value="1" label="3-9 Months"></option>
  <option value="2" label="9-15 Months"></option>
  <option value="3" label="15-24 Months"></option>
  <option value="4" label=" >24 Months"></option>
 
</datalist>









</div>

       

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Somebody help me out with this?

**Thank you**

Comment: Have you checked this https://codepen.io/KristjanLaane/pen/XMwdVW ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242860/range-slider-vertically-with-label

Comment: It's not work for me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Range Slider Vertically with Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242860/range-slider-vertically-with-label)